# Missing argument in syntax-rules Hygienic macro call from Scheme R5RS example

Tags: macros, scheme

I have one more questions about Hygienic macros in Scheme, consider example from [R5RS](https://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.3)

```
(let-syntax ((when (syntax-rules ()
                     ((when test stmt1 stmt2 ...)
                      (if test
                          (begin stmt1
                                 stmt2 ...))))))
  (let ((if #t))
    (when if (set! if 'now))
    if))
```

Why it match if the pattern have 3 arguments and ellipsis that can match empty list?

It's called with 2 arguments `if` and `(set! if 'now)`. What should be `...` bind to, if `stmt2` can be bind to empty list? This is kind of non Lispy if ... is just nothing. Is that true?

What should be the expansion of when in this context? What is the value of `stmt2`?

Why this don't work but the first code does?

```
(let-syntax ((when (syntax-rules ()
                     ((when test stmt1 stmt2 ...)
                      (if test
                          (begin stmt1
                                 stmt2 ...))))))
    (when if 10))
```

it work in Kawa but not in Guile, is that the bug in Guile and it should in fact work like in Kawa?

And one more question why it don't evaluate to `nil`? If next element in list after `10`, is `nil` so `stmt2` should be `nil`? R5RS is not very helpful in that regard.

I'm asking this because I've just finsihed renaming scheme for my macro system in LIPS Scheme and when I'm pattern matching I've got comparison of `stmt2` and `nil` and there is also `...` left. Should in this case `...` just be ignored and `stmt2` should be `nil`? And it should match even that there is one less symbol in pattern? This is really confusing.

What should be the expansion of last snippet of code?

**EDIT:**

One more thought

```
(let-syntax ((when (syntax-rules ()
                     ((when test stmt1 . stmt2)
                      (if test
                          (begin stmt1
                                 stmt2))))))
    (when if 10))
```

This works in Kawa and return `nil` as expected but in Guile it throw exception, I consider Kawa Scheme to be better in following spec.

But why it even match the pattern if there are not enough arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is very non lispy that we have a modifier `...` that changes the meaning of element in front. eg.  `something ...` is basically similar to `. something` except it works with structures like this:

```
(define-syntax my-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ((a b) ...)
        body1 bodyn ...)
     ((lambda (a ...) 
        body1 bodyn ...) 
      b ...))))
```

Notice I use `body1` ro require at least one expression in the body since `bodyn ...` can be zero or more elements. This will turn:

```
(my-let ()
  test)
==> 
((lambda () test))
```

As well as

```
(my-let ((a b) (c d))
  test1 test2)
==> 
((lambda (a c)
   test1 test2)
 b 
 d)
```

My example cannot be rewritten with cons syntax, but basically using `.` works the same way as rest arguments in the pattern and `.` in a quote:

```
'(a b . (c d)) 
; ==> (a b c d)
```

Your `when` would not work with more than one expression. 
eg.

```
(let-syntax ((when (syntax-rules ()
                     ((when test stmt1 . stmt2)
                      (if test
                          (begin stmt1
                                 stmt2))))))
    (define if #t)
    (when if (display 'true) #t))
```

Imagine that all report bindings also exist under `r5rs:` prefix. The expansion will become:

```
(r5rs:if if
         (begin (display 'true)
                (#t)))
; ERROR: Application not a procedure: #t
```

This is correct:

```
(let-syntax ((when (syntax-rules ()
                     ((when test stmt1 . stmt2)
                      (if test
                          (begin stmt1
                                 . stmt2))))))
    (define if #t)
    (when if (display 'true) #t))
; ==> #t (prints true)
```

Comment: What about this `((a b) ...)`  is this something like always split the the list in expression there is need to be `a ...` so If I have `((foo bar baz) ...)` I need to have 3 ellipsis always with `foo ...` `bar ...` and `baz ...`, do you know of any resource that explain all use cases or is there only two of them? after list which is basically same as `((a b) ...)` === `(a b) (a2 b2) (a3 b3))` and they are only in fact to symbols? I wanted to ask another question how multiple ellipsis are expanded but this seems to answer my questions they are names before the ellipsis.

Comment: @jcubic Not quite. You need to have ellipsis in the expansion for all symbols in the structure that has ellipsis in the pattern. Eg. `(foo bar baz) ...` in the pattern can have `(foo baz) ...` in one place and `bar ...` in another and it is satisfied. As with everything else a symbol in the pattern is but a variable and can represent any scheme data unless the variable itself is in the literal list where every mention only means that symbol and nothing else.

Comment: I'll ask another question since there is more things to cover with ellipsis e.g. what should `(foo baz) ...` be expanded into.

Comment: Here is the question [What are all the cases of ellipsis in Scheme pattern matching Hygienic Macros System](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61202006/387194)